# Expected identifier or ´(´ bracket error(?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I got this error when I'm trying to add core data to my single view project, I'm following the guide thats here http://blog.shalomfriss.com/?p=1016 . I got this error at my first bracket in my AppDelegate-m file, the bracket thats over  `- (void)saveContext;` . I'm gonna put the code  here also so i can get some help, but I think the problem is somewhere whit all of the brackets and I have been trying to fix it now but I can't get it to work so thats why I'm posting my question here:).

**AppDelegate h - file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate: UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic)  UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

-(void)saveContext;
-(NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

**and here are the AppDelegate m -file**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@implementation AppDelegate;

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
@end



{

- (void)saveContext

    {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] &amp;&amp; ![managedObjectContext save:&amp;error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
            }
        }
    }


    #pragma mark - Core Data stack

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
    {
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];{
        if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        }
            return _managedObjectContext;
    }

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
    {
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil)
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyDataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
    }

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
    {
        if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourDataBaseName.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
        if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&amp;error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();

        }
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }


#pragma mark - Applications Documents directory


- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
    {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    }

@end
```

so, the error are in the m-file at the first bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `@end` statement and bracket in the implementation file is spurious:

```
@end    // remove

{       // remove

- (void)saveContext
```

Comment: i hade fixed that error, but now I'm getting missing context for method declaration at the -(void);